# query en my mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

hola amigos me podrian ayudar a completar un query [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo estos registros, de los que tengo que obtener la jornada 1 la fecha de inicio y la fecha de fin
la jornada dos fecha de inicio y fecha fin y asi con los demas, es lo obtengo asi:

```
(SELECT date_game_large FROM tabla where journay=1 ORDER BY date_game_large LIMIT 1) as date_start;
(SELECT date_game_large FROM tabla where journay=1 ORDER BY date_game_large DESC LIMIT 1) as date_end;
```

estoy haciendo este query para que lo haga para todas las jornadas:

```
SELECT id_competition,
journay,
(SELECT date_game_large FROM tabla where journay=1 ORDER BY date_game_large LIMIT 1) as date_start,
(SELECT date_game_large FROM tabla where journay=1 ORDER BY date_game_large DESC LIMIT 1) as date_end
FROM tabla GROUP by journay
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quedan de esta manera

pero solo lo hace con la 1er jornada, no se como guardar el valor de jornada y pasarlo al where para que lo haga para todas
o como hacer para que lo haga jornada por jornada

me podrian ayudar, saludos

Comment: No sé si he entendido muy bien lo que has preguntado pero por el título quieres obtener el primer y último registro. Te recomiendo usar UNION.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puedes hacerlo usando [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html), del modo siguiente:

---

**[<kbd>Demo SQL Fiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f346e/3)**

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE jornadas
    (`id_competition` int, `journay` int, `date_start` int, `date_end` int)
;

INSERT INTO jornadas
    (`id_competition`, `journay`, `date_start`, `date_end`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1472236200, 1472236500),
    (1, 2, 1472236700, 1472236900),
    (1, 3, 1472237100, 1472237200),
    (2, 4, 1482236200, 1482236500),
    (2, 5, 1482236700, 1482236900),
    (2, 6, 1482237100, 1482237200),
    (3, 7, 1492236200, 1492236500),
    (3, 8, 1492236700, 1492236900),
    (3, 9, 1492237100, 142237200)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select id_competition, journay as first_journay, date_start, date_end
  from (
    select j1.id_competition, j1.journay, j1.date_start, j1.date_end
    from jornadas j1
    group by j1.journay

    union

    select j2.id_competition, j2.journay, j2.date_start, j2.date_end
    from jornadas j2
    group by j2.journay

  ) tabla_union
group by id_competition
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f346e/3/0)**:

```
| id_competition | first_journay | date_start |   date_end |
|----------------|---------------|------------|------------|
|              1 |             1 | 1472236200 | 1472236500 |
|              2 |             4 | 1482236200 | 1482236500 |
|              3 |             7 | 1492236200 | 1492236500 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitas un `GROUP BY` con `MIN`/`MAX`:

```
select journay,
       min(date_game_large) as date_start,
       max(date_game_large) as date_end
  from tabla
 group by journay
 order by journay
```